# Why std::binary_search on an array give different results in cmd and linux terminal?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, g++, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was trying to solve a [codeforces problem](https://codeforces.com/contest/270/problem/A), which required me to find the interior angles of polygons using the formula:

> ((n-2)*180)/n

; where 'n' is number of polygon sides. I took an array of size: 5 to store the angles of triangle(n=3) and square(n=4). The following code was written to search for an angle(60 degrees) on the array:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arr [5];
    
    for(int n=3; n<5; n++){
            arr[n] = ((n-2)*180)/n;
            cout << "arr["<<n<<"] = "<< arr[n];
            cout<<endl;
    }

    if(binary_search(arr, arr+5,60)){
               cout << "YES"<<"\n";
    }
    else{
               cout<< "NO"<<"\n";
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling and running it on the Command Prompt (cmd), I got the following unexpected result:

> ```
> arr[3] = 60 
> arr[4] = 90
> NO
> ```

Later I tried the same code on Windows Subsystem for Linux, and got the following correct output:

> ```
> arr[3] = 60 
> arr[4] = 90
> YES
> ```

Why is the std::binary_search() function for 60 in array returning false on cmd? Even thoug its stored at index 3.
And why is it working on linux terminal?

### Compiler and C++ used

| System | g++ --version | C++ standard |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cmd (Windows) | g++ (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-5) 8.2.0 | C++14 |
| linux terminal(wsl) | g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0 | C++14 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you got different answers is due to the undefined behavior generated by the fact that a chunk of the array is not initialized.

But if you really want to understand why the first compiler gave an answer different from the second, it's necessary to see the machine code generated by each compiler.

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/scch5o8x3) and [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Poax98MxK) are the machine code generated by gcc 8.2 and gcc 9.3 in an x86-64 architecture.This behavior seems to be just architecture dependent (not dependent on the OS) because I got the same results as you for each compiler.

Answer (score 5):

You don't initialize all of the array, which means some elements will have *indeterminate* values. Using such indeterminate values in any way will lead to *undefined behavior*.

If some of the elements should not be used, you need to initialize them to some value which will satisfy the binary search requirements (the array being ordered), like for example zero:

```
int arr[5] = { 0 };  // Initialize all elements to zero
```

Another option is to only use the initialized parts of the array when doing your search:

```
binary_search(arr + 3, arr + 5, 60)
```